# Incremento de Data +1 Month (considerando dias, mês e ano)

Tags: php, loop, datetime

É o seguinte, em um sistema que estou desenvolvendo, preciso incrementar uma data. Abaixo segue o código que eu consegui desenvolver até o momento que este funciona perfeitamente para incremento mesmo considerando os dias "29 - 31", mas quando eu coloco dia "05" ele *buga* ao passar de ano, porque não valida o primeiro `if`.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){ 
        $data = '2019-01-05'; // TESTE 02 '2019-01-31'
        if($i >= 1){ 
            $numMesAtual = $i - 1;
            $mesAtual = date("m", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data)) . "+$numMesAtual month"));
            $mesProximo  = date("m", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data)) . "+$i month"));

            if($mesAtual == $mesProximo-1){
                $data = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data)) . "+$i month"));
            } else{
                $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data)) . "last day of +$i month"));
            }
        }
        echo $i ."- ". $data ."<br/>";
    }
```

```
---------------------
RETORNO ESPERADO
---------------------
1- 2019-02-05
2- 2019-03-05
3- 2019-04-05
4- 2019-05-05
5- 2019-06-05
6- 2019-07-05
7- 2019-08-05
8- 2019-09-05
9- 2019-10-05
10- 2019-11-05
11- 2019-12-05
12- 2020-01-05 - //Porém o código atual retorna 2020-01-31, porque entra no else{}, isso ocorre porque ao passar de ano o número do mês e tornou 1
```

Comment: `$numMesAtual = $i - 1;` quando for `1`, vai ficar zero em `+$numMesAtual month")` não entendi muito bem o seu problema.

Comment: Também não consegui entender o problema. Executei aqui e a saída pareceu estar condizente com o código. Qual era a saída esperada?

Comment: Beleza, vamos lá! Desculpem, vou tentar esclarecer a saída que eu esperava.

Comment: 1- 2019-02-05
2- 2019-03-05
3- 2019-04-05
4- 2019-05-05
5- 2019-06-05
6- 2019-07-05
7- 2019-08-05
8- 2019-09-05
9- 2019-10-05
10- 2019-11-05
11- 2019-12-05
12- 2020-01-31 - Aqui está o problema, pelo fato do ano ser diferente ele entra no else{}

Comment: Sim, por que você fez essa condição se não quer que isso ocorra?

Comment: Fiz para validar quando o dia for entre 29-31 e não existir em algum mês, por exemplo em janeiro temos 31 dias, enquanto em fevereiro 28, neste caso ele iria incrementar para o último dia do próximo mês.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso ocorre em todas as viradas de ano, o motivo é sua comparação:

```
if($mesAtual == $mesProximo-1){
```

O `$mesAtual` será 11 e o próximo mês seria 0. Uma correção seria comparar o ano, como:

```
$anoAtual = date("Y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data)) . "+$numMesAtual month"));
$anoProximo  = date("Y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data)) . "+$i month"));

if($mesAtual == $mesProximo-1 || $anoAtual != $anoProximo) {
```

*Embora, acredito que o código ainda não faça muito sentido.*

Comment: Então, foi a forma que encontrei de fazer, eu estou fazendo um sistema que tem parcelas, quando a pessoa parcela em "X Meses" eu preciso incrementar as datas, porém caso sejam dias de finais de mês, eu preciso dessa função, porque muitas vezes não existe o dia 31, neste caso eu quero que a parcela seja no último dia próximo mês, se encontrar outra solução melhor, estou aberto para sugestões, mas de toda forma muito obrigado, o seu código resolveu o meu problema.

Comment: @LucasSantos, pessoalmente nunca passei por isso (já que sempre fiz cobranças a cada 30 dias, não "a cada mês"). Acho que uma melhor solução seria definir outra data de inicio quando o dia inicial é > 28. Isso é, as parcelas só podem ser definidas entre dia 1 até 28, assim o usuário também já sabe quando tem que pagar. Se ele inciar o contrato no dia 31/07, todas as próximas faturas seriam referentes ao dia 28 (28/08, 28/09, 28/10...), dai não teria nenhuma problema. Dessa forma, basta verificar se o dia da `$data` é > 28, se for define o dia para 28 e depois só soma com 1 mês.